# Update Maven's changes.xml automatically from git commit messages

Tags: git, maven, maven-changes-plugin

Is there a Maven plugin that generates the `changes.xml` file for the changes plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/index.html) automatically using the information provided by the Git commits?

This git log

```
commit af2ce13dc277d862ffddf4c03c809b73587188e3
Author: Stefan Birkner <mail@stefan-birkner.de>
Date:   Tue Feb 11 00:13:53 2014 +0100

    [maven-release-plugin] prepare release system-rules-1.5.0

commit e78934311d68a0fb081d7a46e313952e21bd93f8
Author: Stefan Birkner <mail@stefan-birkner.de>
Date:   Wed Feb 5 00:10:25 2014 +0100

    Fix wrong method names in class' Javadoc.


commit 42c054881fff69f682d7f3f6ecee51974f515d80
Author: Stefan Birkner <mail@stefan-birkner.de>
Date:   Wed Sep 11 10:26:23 2013 +0200

    [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
```

should be used to create this changes.xml section:

```
<release version="1.5.0" date="1024-02-11">
  <action dev="Stefan Birkner" type="fix" date="2014-02-05">
    Fix wrong method names in class' Javadoc.
  </action>
</release>
```

Comment: You don't use any *issue tracker* ? Like GitHub's issue tracker, Jira, Trac, etc. It would be simpler.

Comment: Or you may try to get help with *git help log*. There are options to filter with *--grep* and apply patterns...

Comment: I'm looking for library/plugin that is doing this. Otherwise I write a plugin by myself. But I won't repeat work that is already done by someone else.

Comment: @StefanBirkner, did you resolve that one? how? I have the same issue.

Comment: I didn't. I think the best solution is to write or extend a Maven plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The [maven-gitlog-plugin](http://danielflower.github.io/maven-gitlog-plugin/) plugin generates a changelog (not exactly generates your `changes.xml` file).

Also the official maven changes plugin has now support for github. See [configuring github report](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/examples/configuring-github-report.html).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with [Git Changelog Maven Plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-maven-plugin). There are a bunch of examples in the [example pom.xml](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-maven-plugin/blob/master/git-changelog-maven-plugin-example/pom.xml).